# Complex redux-loop examples?

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, redux, redux-loop

Are there any examples of using `redux-loop` to handle complex ajax workflows? The official repo is very minimalistic. From the one example in the wild I was able to find (https://hackernoon.com/why-i-wrote-a-redux-async-outerware-277d450dba74#.2ocaloc58), it seems that redux-loop is very similar to redux-thunk.

Here are some examples of complex ajax workflows:

- *Ajax Workflow1*. User selects two different filters on a results table. Each filter initiates an ajax request, which then resolve out of order. The results table should show the correct filter selection. Errors should not update the results table.
- *Ajax Workflow 2*

  - User starts a report generation (which is a long running process).
  - User switches to another report. It should either cancel or ignore the  pending “wait for report” action.
- *More complex workflow* (based on an old redux-saga example)

  - User presses log-in button, which starts an ajax request to get an auth token
  - Either

    - User immediately presses log-out button, which should cancel/ignore the pending auth action
    - OR it should store the auth token when it resolves
  - Should clear the auth token after logout or if login error occurs

Answer (score 2):

I will give a shot at the second workflow (login).

Before going into the code, it's worth noting `redux-loop` is a lot simpler and offers less than `redux-saga` in terms of async control flow. But in the spirit of `Elm`, the focus is on data flow - not surprisingly is typically achieved by data types. Therefore it is helpful to think from the perspective of a statically typed language. In `Haskell` or `Elm`, it's probably beneficial to model the problem by data type, which itself encodes a state machine:

```
data LoginStatus data err =
    LoggedOut       | 
  , LoggedIn data   |
  , LoginError err  | 
  , Pending
```

Where `data` and `err` are type variables represent login data type (tokens) and login errors. JavaScript being dynamically typed, does not have the benefit expressing the same idea - but there are a lot of dynamic tricks one can use to mimic tagged union types like `LoginStatus`. Without further ago, here's the code:

```
import {match} from "single-key";

export default function reducer(state, action) {
  return match(state, {
    LoggedOut : () => loggedOutReducer(state, action),
    LoggedIn  : () => loggedInReducer(state, action),
    Pending : () => pendingReducer(state, action),
    LoginError : () => loginErrorReducer(state, action)
  });
}
```

Here I will use a simple and lesser known library [singe-key](https://www.npmjs.com/package/single-key) to achieve very basic run time union types. A "single-key" object as it's name suggest, is an object with just a key and a value, such as `{ a: 1 }` ("a" is the key, and 1 is the value). We shall model the state with single-key objects - different keys represent different variants of `LoginStatus`. A few example states:

```
{
  LoggedOut : true
}


{
  LoggedIn : {
    token : 1235,
    user : { firstName: "John" }
  }
}

{
  Pending : true
}
```

With that cleared up, here are the sub-reducers used in the main reducer:

```
// state :: { LoggedIn: {/* some data * } }
function loggedInReducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === LOGOUT) {
    return {
      LoggedOut : true
    };
  }
  return state;
}
// state :: { Pending : true }
function pendingReducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === LOGIN_SUCCESS) {
    return {
      LoggedIn : {
        token : action.payload.token,
        user  : action.payload.user
      }
    };
  }
  if (action.type === LOGIN_ERROR) {
    return {
      LoginError : action.payload;  
    };
  }
  if (action.type === LOGOUT) {
    return {
      LoggedOut : true  
    };
  }
  return state;
}
// state :: { LoggedOut : true }
function loggedOutReducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === LOGIN) {
    return loop({ Pending: true }, Effects.promise(loginRequest));  
  }
  return state;
}
// state :: { LoginError : error }
function loginErrorReducer(state, action) {
  if (action.type === LOGIN) {
    return loop({ Pending: true }, Effects.promise(loginRequest));  
  }
  return { LoggedOut : true }; 
}
```

These are like transitions in a finite state machine, except sometimes with data attached to the state. Each individual reducers are fairly simple and handles very few action types. Only two reducers return effects:

```
return loop({ Pending: true }, Effects.promise(loginRequest));
```

This transitions the state from `LoggedOut`/`LoginError` to `Pending` and specify some side effects - which will be scheduled by `redux-loop`. You may even merge the two variants into one: `{ LoggedOut : error | null }`, but I feel having a seperate `LoginError` state is beneficial in the long run.

With some notion of data types, this problem can be easier to reason about than it first appears; you can do the same thing with reducer structured roughly the same and use just `redux-thunk`.

Comment: I appreciate the response but... the problem with this approach is that it mixes responsibilities. Async workflow + "normal" state. This leads to complex reducers. In real projects, that means you just made it easier to create brittle code.. Also, you haven't addressed how to actually do the workflows above.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is reasonable criticism. For the last point, I believe I have mostly addressed how it would work. Well, since I have some free time at hand today, just made a working example using the reducer layout explained here. It has both a `redux-loop` and `redux-sage` implementation with almost identical reducers: [https://github.com/yiransheng/redux-login-examples](https://github.com/yiransheng/redux-login-examples)

Comment: What's good is your idea of explicitly enumerating types. Unfortunately, as they say in America, "You're beating a dead horse." In addition, to the mixing of concerns, you don't have a dedicated API for handling asynchronicity. Hence, in real-world projects, code gets very, very complex (and repetitive). For example, you don't handle the "cancel" case. Secondly, FRP/sagas win in testing. You don't need mocks.